# MVC 6 Multiple Get Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

I am trying to support multiple Get() methods per controller, as well as just specially named methods accessible through web api. I have done this in MVC 5, but can't seem to figure out how it is done in MVC 6. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use attribute routing link this -

```
[Route("api/[controller]")] /* this is the defualt prefix for all routes, see line 20 for overridding it */
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet] // this api/Values
    public string Get()
    {
        return string.Format("Get: simple get");
    }

    [Route("GetByAdminId")] /* this route becomes api/[controller]/GetByAdminId */
    public string GetByAdminId([FromQuery] int adminId)
    {
        return $"GetByAdminId: You passed in {adminId}";
    }

    [Route("/someotherapi/[controller]/GetByMemberId")] /* note the / at the start, you need this to override the route at the controller level */
    public string GetByMemberId([FromQuery] int memberId)
    {
        return $"GetByMemberId: You passed in {memberId}";
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("IsFirstNumberBigger")] /* this route becomes api/[controller]/IsFirstNumberBigger */
    public string IsFirstNumberBigger([FromQuery] int firstNum, int secondNum)
    {
        if (firstNum > secondNum)
        {
            return $"{firstNum} is bigger than {secondNum}";
        }
        return $"{firstNum} is NOT bigger than {secondNum}";
    }
}
```

See here for more detail - http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2016/01/asp-net-5-web-api-controller-with-multiple-get-methods/

Comment: Thanks! This was a better solution, as I can use normal nested routes.

Comment: kindly see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46680893/passing-multiple-parameters-to-web-api-get-method)

Answer (score 30):

You cannot have multiple Get methods with same url pattern. You can use attribute routing and setup multiple GET method's for different url patterns.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class IssuesController : Controller
{
    // GET: api/Issues
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "item 1", "item 2" };
    }

    // GET api/Issues/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "request for "+ id;
    }

    // GET api/Issues/special/5
    [HttpGet("special/{id}")]
    public string GetSpecial(int id)
    {
        return "special request for "+id;
    }
    // GET another/5
    [HttpGet("~/another/{id}")]
    public string AnotherOne(int id)
    {
        return "request for AnotherOne method with id:" + id;
    }
    // GET api/special2/5
    [HttpGet()]
    [Route("~/api/special2/{id}")]
    public string GetSpecial2(int id)
    {
        return "request for GetSpecial2 method with id:" + id;
    }
}
```

You can see that i used both `HttpGet` and `Route` attributes for defining the route patterns.

With the above configuration, you you will get the below responses

> **Request Url** : yourSite/api/issues/

Result     `["value1","value2"]`

> **Request Url** : yourSite/api/issues/4

Result     `request for 4`

> **Request Url** : yourSite/api/special2/6

Result     `request for GetSpecial2 method with id:6`

> **Request Url** : yourSite/another/3

Result     `request for AnotherOne method with id:3`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.

Comment: kindly see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46680893/passing-multiple-parameters-to-web-api-get-method)