# Passing multiple parameters to web API GET method

Tags: linq, rest, get, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have created a `WEB API` using `MySQL` Database. The API works as expected for now. I sent a meter serial number and a date time parameter and then GET the expected result. Below is my controller

```
public MDCEntities medEntitites = new MDCEntities();
public HttpResponseMessage GetByMsn(string msn, DateTime dt)
    {          
        try
        {
            var before = dt.AddMinutes(-5);
            var after = dt.AddMinutes(5);

            var result = medEntitites.tj_xhqd
                         .Where(m =>
                         m.zdjh == msn &&
                         m.sjsj >= before &&
                         m.sjsj <= after).Select(m => new { MSN = m.zdjh, DateTime = m.sjsj, Signal_Strength = m.xhqd }).Distinct();


            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found, result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }
    }
```

Below is my `WebApiConfig` file

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "GetByMsn",
       routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{msn}/{dt}",
       defaults: null,
       constraints: new { msn = @"^[0-9]+$" , dt = @"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$" }
       );
```

The URL is `http://localhost:14909/api/meters/GetByMsn/002999000171/2017-10-10T10:08:20`

The response I GET is

```
[{
    "MSN": "002999000171",
    "DateTime": "2017-10-10T10:04:39",
    "Signal_Strength": "20"
},
{
    "MSN": "002999000171",
    "DateTime": "2017-10-10T10:06:35",
    "Signal_Strength": "19"
},
{
    "MSN": "002999000171",
    "DateTime": "2017-10-10T10:08:31",
    "Signal_Strength": "20"
},
{
    "MSN": "002999000171",
    "DateTime": "2017-10-10T10:10:27",
    "Signal_Strength": "20"
},
{
    "MSN": "002999000171",
    "DateTime": "2017-10-10T10:12:23",
    "Signal_Strength": "20"
}]
```

This all scenario works when a `single serial number` is passed. But at client side there would be more than one different serial numbers. For this I had to make my method to work both for one and more than one serial numbers provided the date time will be the same for all.

```
One solution is to create a new method a pass the multiple serial number strings, but this will not help because the number of serial numbers are dynamic i.e. they may be one, two to 100's. So setting a hard coded method won't be a solution.
```

I have searched for it but most of the times I have found the static method again and again. But this [solution](https://forums.asp.net/post/6077582.aspx) looks some what helpful but again I don't know whether it will work or not.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a custom model to an action method, but I suggest not using the `GET` for you task because `GET` does not have a body.

Instead, use the `SEARCH` verb and put the list of serials number and the date inside a custom model in the body.

```
public class MeterSearchModel 
{
   public List<string> Serials {get;set;}
   public DateTime Date {get;set;}  
}
```

In .NET Core 2 your controller would have something like -

```
[AcceptVerbs("SEARCH")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Search([FromBody] MeterSearchModel model)
{
    //..perform search 
}
```